# Deep in slots vue 2

Tags: vue.js

Does anybody know is there are some limitations on how deep my components with slots can be ?

Now I have 3 components, like

**list.vue**

```
<div class="list">
  <slot name="list" />
</div
```

**wrapper.vue**

```
<list>
<template #list>
   <div>hello</div>
   <slot name="wrapper" />
</template>
</list>
```

**last.vue**

```
<wrapper>
  <template #wrapper>
    <search :value=value />
  </template>
</wrapper>
```

So, i want to transfer some value from last component to search component. On init something is good, but if value is changing in my last component my search component it doesn't see.
Maybe someone know information about max deep for components + slots ?

Comment: There is no limit to slot depth and this should work.  Do you have any error?

Comment: No, I haven't. I see that in my parent component everything is good. I see that my variable is reactive, but in children I see no changes.

Comment: Probably the issue is with your `search` component. Where do you see it's reactive and where do you see no changes?  [See demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/7gjudce0/)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to share your `Search` component and the rest of the other components (namely, the `script` section). There is no limit in the slot depth (whatever that means). I'm assuming you have some other errors in parts you haven't shared. My first guess would be the way you have set the `props` in your `Search` component.

Here is an example of a working version on how you should set a nullable `prop` on a component:

Last.vue

```
<template>
    <Wrapper>
        <template #wrapper>
          <label>
              <input type="text" v-model="value">
          </label>

          <Search :value=value />
        </template>
    </Wrapper>
</template>

<script>
import Wrapper from "@/components/Wrapper";
import Search from "@/components/Search";

export default {
    components: {Search, Wrapper},

    data() {
        return {
            value: null
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Search.vue

```
<template>
    <p>{{ value }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        value: {
            type: String,
            default: null,
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

If this doesn't address your problem, please share the rest of your code and I'd be glad to help!